# Groovy/Grails Tool Suite won't run-app on Mac

Tags: git, macos, grails, groovy

We have a MacBook OSX (10.8.5) that we have installed Groovy Grails Tool Suite 3.6.4. When we import a git project in and try to run-app we get the following error:

```
Description Resource    Path Location   Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    lifeflow_ui Unknown Java Problem
```

That is the only error message we get. Should there be a log file for this? I tried looking for the .log file with no luck.

Comment: Does it work on another project? What's the project? Does it work from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that your project classpath is not correct. `java.lang.Object` cannot be found. It seems like you have no JRE on your project's classpath. I'm not sure why it wasn't added automatically, but you just need to add it yourself.

Something like this:

1. Select project, right-click -> build path -> add libraries -> JRE System Library
2. Choose the JRE that you want to use

This will at least remove the current classpath problems that you have, but it may uncover others.